# Fetching data from external program

Tags: python

I have an external program, [opentrack](https://github.com/opentrack/opentrack), that tracks head position using IR LED's. The position is updated in the program in real-time, but my problem is that I would like to get that data into my python code. Is it possible to do this?

I've been looking into subprocesses and things like that, but I still don't understand how to do it. Sorry for the very general question but I just need someone to point me into the right direction or to tell me that it isn't really possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you linked to clearly lists no fewer than 9 different ways in which opentrack can output the data.

So you need to figure out which one to use, and write Python code to act as a receiver for one of those methods. Perhaps UDP, since that sounds simple enough.

Hint: to decode any binary format, you're probably going to want to become familiar with Python's [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module.

Comment: Thanks! I used UDP and I'm getting some data feed to my python program. However it's in some strange format so I can't really interpret it, but it's definitely a start.